# ROS ERROR: Gradle 'android_10' project refresh failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ros

```
Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

I am trying to use ROSJava in Android Studio 3.0.1 but following the installation instructions given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/indigo/Installation%20-%20ROS%20Development%20Environment) leads to this error in Android Studio. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using Android Studio 2.x.x instead of the newer 3.x.x version.